# Ski simulation - Velocity vector components

Tags: vectors, physics

So I am creating a physics ski simulation as a project on my University and the task that I've been struggling with for a couple of hours is:

**How fast is a Skier moving towards a still obstacle at particular time?**. It's described in the literature as $\nabla r_{ab}$ where $r_{ab}$ is the distance between skier and an obstacle.
[A picture that may be helpful](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhD2k.png)

I've tried multiplying velocity's $x$ and $y$ components by $cos$ of the angles between them and the vector pointing toward the obstacle but didn't get the result I need.

**EDIT**: The things I know about skier are: position $(a_x, a_y)$, velocity $(V_x, V_y)$, forces that he is exposed to. The thing I know about obstacle is it's position $(b_x, b_y)$

Comment: Can you give all quantities or label your picture more accurately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cosine formula should work if you apply it to the actual velocity
vector itself. As you found out, it does not work on the components
of that vector.

Use `sqrt(vx*vx + vy*vy)` to find the magnitude of the skier's
velocity, and something like `atan2(vy, vx)` to find the skier's direction.

For the direction, you may need to swap the `vx` and `vy`, 
change sign, or add a constant to the result, depending on exactly how you
have set up the coordinate system and how your software environment
defines `atan2`. The angle will probably be given in radians,
which is fine since you just need to pass it to `cos`.
Try a few examples, printing out the components and
the calculated angle, until you get it right.

Alternatively, you can evaluate
$$ \frac d{dt} \sqrt{ (x - x_b)^2 + (y - y_b)^2 }
$$
given the skier's position $(x,y)$ and velocity components
$(v_x, v_y)$, taking $\frac d{dt} x = v_x$ and $\frac d{dt} y = v_y$.
But I do it the first way when I program something like this.